# Getting an exception error with my vb.net code

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

Getting a $exception error ""Public member 'Text' on type 'Selection' not found." I'm using visual studio and trying to make a form when click on a button it will scrape text from an open outlook email. shoots out an error when calling emailbody.Text. I'm very new to visual basic so please be easy on me lol. Any help will be great thanks.

```
 Private Sub Pull_info_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Pull_info.Click
    Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application
    Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer = myOlApp.ActiveExplorer
    Dim myOlSel As Outlook.Selection = myOlExp.Selection
    'Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim emailbody As Object

    emailbody = myOlSel

    Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("Ticket\sNumber:\s(.*?)\s-")
    Dim match As Match = regex.Match(emailbody.Text)
    If match.Success Then
        MsgBox(match.Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The selection object appears to have no text property:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.selection_members(v=office.14).aspx

You could use the debugger and see what property/value combinations are available to you, but the documentation I linked to helps also.  You can also see what comes back from ToString() instead of Text, maybe it'll give you what you need.

Comment: Thanks I’ll check that out

Comment: I found this, its not very straightforward to get that text from the object: reference - http://burnignorance.com/c-coding-tips/how-to-programmatically-get-a-selected-text-from-ms-outlook/